# Silverlight OOB Calling Class Library

Tags: silverlight-4.0, silverlight-oob, out-of-browser

I have a class library that reads and writes to a local SQL CE database using Entity Framework 4.2 code first. I want to access the class library from a Silverlight 4 OOB app.

What is the best way to do this?

Do I have to turn the class library into a COM object?

Would it be better to use Silverlight 5?

Comment: I'm a bit late here, but what have you tried? Did you recompile the lib for Silverlight?

Comment: If I recompile the lib for Silverlight I loose the ability to access the file system.

Comment: Ah, I missed the 'local' part about the database.

Answer (score 0):

With both Silverlight 4 and Silverlight 5, if you're using OOB, you can use elevated privileges to get access to lots of things, and with Silverlight 5, that includes the whole file system and P/Invoke if needed.

For that to work, you'll have to sign your app with a code signing certificate.